# Profiles and certificates, what have I done wrong?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

We have an app on AppStore, and we are in progress of making it into two different apps, a Pro and a Lite. When we were developing, we just copied the original project and I made Pro-version, he made Lite-version. Now, I have to change the profiles and certificates and AppID and bundleID etc, but I'm having some trouble doing it..

Because we're actually done with both, I decided to go straight to distribute/release.

I first made an AppID for the new project, called something similar to the other one (+Pro).
Then I configured the distribution Push Notifications service, and requested certificate, and made the .p12 and .pem and whatnot.

Then I went to 'Provisioning'->'Distribution' and made a new profile. This profile used the new AppID. So far so good?

I downloaded the distribution profile, and added it to XCode Organizer. I then went into Build Settings for BOTH target and project, and set `Code Signing Identity->Release->Any iOS SDK->iPhone Distribution(the correct new profile I just made)`. I set the same for Ad-hoc, just in case..

I go to `Product->Edit Scheme`, and set the 'Run appName.app'->Build Configuration to 'Release' insted of 'Debug'. Then I build the project, and scroll down in the project navigator, locate the appName.app, drag it into iTunes, and install it on my device from there.

When I synchronize my phone with iTunes now, it says on my device(loosely translated): `iTunes synchronization - AppName could not install`.
Why? How can the profiles be wrong? I am using the exact same profiles, only new ones called 'appPro' instead of 'app'. New AppID, new BundleID, but my app failes. Or maybe it isn't a profile error?